# Disagreement between AT_SYSINFO_EHDR and /proc/self/maps

Tags: linux, operating-system, system

So I know that AT_SYSINFO_EHDR should contain a pointer to the VDSO.
I also know that the VDSO shows up in /proc/[pid]/maps.

But it looks like the outputs don't match.
For example, take this run:

```
LD_SHOW_AUXV=1 cat /proc/self/maps
[...]
AT_SYSINFO_EHDR: 0x2aaaaaac6000
[...]
2aaaaaac6000-2aaaaaac7000 r-xp 2aaaaaac6000 00:00 0
[...]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vdso]
[...]
```

Why is there a difference? Am I missing something?

[EDIT] 
Okay, I looked at the outputs in other machines and the outputs match there. So I guess this is something specific to that one machine. I would still appreciate an explanation if you have one.